# ESP8266 analogRead() microphone Input into playable audio

Tags: audio, arduino, esp8266, microphone, adc

My goal is to record audio using an electret microphone hooked into the analog pin of an esp8266 (12E) and then be able to play this audio on another device. My circuit is:

[image: Electret microphone to esp8266]

In order to check the output of the microphone I connected the circuit to the oscilloscope and got this:
[image: Electret microphone is connected to oscilloscope]

In the "gif" above you can see the waves made by my voice when talking to microphone.
here is my code on esp8266:

```
void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print(" ");
}
```

I would like to play the audio on the "Audacity" software in order to have an understanding of the result. Therefore, I copied the numbers from the serial monitor and paste it into the python code that maps the data to (-1,1) interval:

```
def mapPoint(value, currentMin, currentMax, targetMin, targetMax):
    currentInterval = currentMax - currentMin
    targetInterval = targetMax - targetMin

    valueScaled = float(value - currentMin) / float(currentInterval)

    return round(targetMin + (valueScaled * targetInterval),5)

class mapper():
    def __init__(self,raws):
        self.raws=raws.split(" ")
        self.raws=[float(i) for i in self.raws]

    def mapAll(self):
        self.mappeds=[mapPoint(i,min(self.raws),max(self.raws),-1,1) for i in self.raws ]
        self.strmappeds=str(self.mappeds).replace(",","").replace("]","").replace("[","")
        return self.strmappeds
```

Which takes the string of numbers, map them on the target interval (-1 ,+1) and return a space (" ") separated string of data ready to import into Audacity software. (`Tools>Sample Data Import` and then select the text file including the data). The result of importing data from almost 5 seconds voice:
[image: data imported into audacity]

which is about half a second and when I play I hear unintelligible noise. I also tried lower frequencies but there was only noise there, too.

The suspected causes for the problem are:

1- Esp8266 has not the capability to read the analog pin fast enough to return meaningful data (which is probably not the case since it's clock speed is around 100MHz).

2- The way software is gathering the data and outputs it is not the most optimized way (In the loop, Serial.print, etc.)

3- The microphone circuit output is too noisy. (which might be, but as observed from the oscilloscope test, my voice has to make a difference in the output audio. Which was not audible from the audacity)

4- The way I mapped and prepared the data for the Audacity.

- Is there something else I could try?
- Are there similar projects out there? (which to my surprise I couldn't find anything which was done transparently!)
- What can be the right way to do this? (since it can be a very useful and economic method for recording, transmitting and analyzing audio.)

Comment: This might be more relevant on [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) as the problem is not fully programming. Breaking down your list of problems. 1. 100MHz _should_ be fast enough, but bear in mind anything else you are doing in the sketch. Micro Python _may_ be a little too slow for this kind of work. 2. Serial comms are sub optimal for audio and you will be limited by your baud rate. Typically an audio interface will be at least double buffered, so while the device fills one memory space while another is read by the connected machine.

Comment: You'd technically need 2 ESPs to achieve that. One which round robin writes to some external memory and another which sends the data. **3.** The input will be incredibly noisy. It's not likely to be a tolerant mic, but you should be able to get something intelligible. You just won't be winning a grammy any time soon. **4.** Maybe, you'll want to make sure you are writing the raw bytes. The ESP8266 ADC pin only has a 10-bit resolution. You'll be wasting a lot of cycles converting to 32-bit float and scaling to `-1.0f` and `1.0f`.

Comment: If you want to record, then playback you can do a lot of this offline. You only need to save the data to some memory and read it back later. You can then do what ever post-processing is needed to scale the raw bytes to a suitable audio range. 10-bit isn't standard so you can either scale to 16-bit and keep the resolution or scale down to 8-bit and save space. 16-bit probably makes the most sense

Comment: You now have a problem of data storage. SD cards are quite slow so you will get discontinuity in the audio signal without double buffering (i.e. x2 ESPs and shared memory). You could write to FRAM. You would need at about 512KB of FRAM for ~5 seconds of audio. You would then need to write 2 programme or write some functionality that will **1** record the signal to RAM **2** On, for instance, a button press stop recording and start dumping the contents of RAM to an SD Card or over a Serial connection.

Comment: A lot of modern audio equipment (like the microphone on a smart phone) won't read in PCM data like you are with the ESP analog chip, but rather they will use some kind of [sigma delta modulator converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation) circuit. Make sure your expectations aren't too out of line so you won't feel disappointed with the final result

Comment: What is your target sample rate?  Right now, you have no control at all over your sample rate.  What is your microprocessor? If it's a UNO,   At 9600 baud, it takes 1 ms to transfer 1 byte of data, if each sample you send takes between 1 and 3ms, your maximum sample rate is 330Hz, but since you make no attempt to pace the code the output sounds like 'garble garble garble', that's normal.

Comment: Once you have managed your sampling rate, you may need to add a low pass filter on the input, to eliminate the roll-over of frequencies above 1/2 of your sample rate, otherwise, you will still end up with unintelligible noise on the output side.

Comment: Keep in mind that using millis() to pace the sampling can only give you a 1kH sampling rate, which is very poor, so look into using a timer interrupt.  Also, if you are using a UNO @16MHz, the default max sampling rate of the ADC is around 10KHz, so a call to analogRead() should block for about 100us, which is a lot, so you'll need to aces sthe hardware directly.

Comment: Oh.  One last thing.  There is no bias on the ADC input.  There should be a 2.5V bias resistor divider there, and ideally two voltage limiting diodes as well, 1N914 or 1N4148 will do fine.  You may end up frying your ADC by feeding it negative voltages.  Best would be to add a small amplifier before the AN input.  What is the output impedance of your mic?

Comment: @fdcpp 
1-  I am using Arduino to program the esp (not MicroPython).
2- My baud rate is 115200. Wouldn't it be enough to get a sample rate of 4KHz? 3- I want to achieve my goal without extra equipment (e.g. SD card ram,

Comment: @michaël-roy 1-I want to achieve  the highest sample rate possible (No delay in the loop) . 2- As I have mentioned in the question title and in the question I am using ESP8266. 3. I have posted my code in the question (haven't used millis()).

Comment: @michaël-roy I think the key to the problem is (as you have mentioned) controlling the sampling rate. what mechanism can be used to do that? (8KHz would be great)

Comment: Apologies I saw the Python code and assumed. A sample rate of 4KHz is not going to yield wonderful results, something akin to an old telephone line. @MichaëlRoy is correct, you’ll need to low pass your signal to discard anything above 2KHz. 8KHz is maybe a little lofty for pcm audio. If you look at ESP8266 audio projects they’re typically dealing with compressed audio streams, not collecting then sending raw sample data. You fill a large buffer of ~8k samples from expanding some mp3 frames, this then buys enough time between writing out each sample to collect and expand subsequent frames.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your project:

You do not set a bias voltage on A0.  The ADC can only measure voltages between Ground and VCC. When removing the microphone from the circuit, the voltage at A0 should be close to VCC/2. This is usually achieved by adding a voltage divider between VCC and GND made of 2 resistors, and connected directly to A0. Between the cap and A0.

Also, your circuit looks weird... Is the 47uF cap connected directly to the 3.3V ?  If that's the case, you should connect it to pin 2 of the microphone instead.  This would also indicate that right now your ADC is only recording noise (no bias voltage will do that).

You do not pace you input, meaning that you do not have a constant sampling rate.  That is a very important issue.  I suggest you set yourself a realistic target that is well within the limits of the ADC, and the limits of your serial port.  The transfer rate in bytes/sec of a serial port is usually equal to baud-rate / 8.  For 9600 bauds, that's only about 1200 bytes/sec, which means that once converted to text, you max *transfer* rate drops to about 400 samples per second.  This issue needs to be addressed and the max calculated **before** you begin, as the max attainable overall sample rate is the maximum of the sample rate from the ADC and the transfer rate of the serial port.

The way to grab samples depends a lot on your needs and what you are trying to do with this project, your audio bandwidth, resolution  and audio quality requirements for the application and the amount of work you can put into it.  Reading from a loop as you are doing now *may* work with a fast enough serial port, but the quality will always be poor.

The way that is usually done is with a timer interrupt starting the ADC measurement and an ADC interrupt grabbing the result and storing it in a small FIFO, while the main loop transfers from this ADC fifo to the serial port, along the other tasks assigned to the chip.  This cannot be done directly with the Arduino libraries, as you need to control the ADC directly to do that.

Here a short checklist of things to do:

1. Get the full ESP8266 datasheet from Expressif.  Look up the actual specs of the ADC, mainly: the sample rates and resolutions available with your oscillator, and also its electrical constraints, at least its input voltage range and input impedance.
2. Once you know these numbers, set yourself some target, the math needed for successful project need input numbers.  What is your application?  Do you want to record audio or just detect a nondescript noise? What are the **minimum** requirements needed for things to work?
3. Look up in the Arduino documentartion how to set up a timer interrupt and an ADC interrupt.
4. Look up in the datasheet which registers you'll need to access to configure and run the ADC.
5. Fix the voltage bias issue on the ADC input. Nothing can work before that's done, and you do not want to destroy your processor.
6. Make sure the input AC voltage (the 'swing' voltage) is large  enough to give you the results you want.  It is not unusual to have to amplify a mic signal (with an opamp or a transistor), just for impedance matching.
7. Then you can start writing code.

This may sound awfully complex for such a small task, but that's what the average day of an embedded programmer looks like.

[EDIT]  Your circuit would work a lot better if you simply replaced the 47uF DC blocking capacitor by a series resistor. Its value should be in the 2.2k to 7.6k range, to keep the circuit impedance within the 10k Ohms or so needed for the ADC.  This would insure that the input voltage to A0 is within the operating limits of the ADC (GND-3.3V on the NodeMCU board, 0-1V with bare chip).

The signal may still be too weak for your application, though. What is the amplitude of the signal on your scope? How many bits of resolution does that range cover once converted by the ADC?  Example, for a .1V peak to peak signal (SIG = 0.1), an ADC range of 0-3.3V (RNG = 3.3) and 10 bits of resolution (RES = 1024), you'll have

```
binary-range = RES * (SIG / RNG) 
             = 1024 * (0.1 / 3.3)
             = 1024 * .03
             = 31.03
```

A range of 31, which means around Log2(31) (~= 5) useful bits of resolution, is that enough for your application ?

As an aside note:  The ADC will give you positive values, with a DC offset, You will probably need to filter the digital output with a DC blocking filter before playback.  https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/dc_offset.html

Comment: Good breakdown of the problem. This library is likely relevant https://github.com/khoih-prog/ESP8266TimerInterrupt

Comment: @michaël-roy As it can be observed from the oscilloscope test the circuit is responding to the sound. However, I had uploaded the wrong schematic (which  now I have replaced with the correct one).

Comment: What is the DC offset at A0 ?  The ADC can only measure voltages from GND to VCC.  Any negative voltage on A0 will translate to digital noise, and **can destroy the ADC**, I've seen that happen more than once.